# How to check valid html structure in Java using regex

Tags: java, html, regex

I want to know the input html string is vaild or not.
I researched various HTML parser. But anything doesn't have validating html method.
Jsoup is almost same what I want. But it generates valid parsed html.
Basically I want to check valid html structure as below.

```
<html>
<head>~</head>
<body>~</body>
</html>
```

So, I wrote code in Java.

```
String html = "<html><head><title>asdf</title></Head><body>asfd</body></html>";
String compile = "(?i)<html.*>.*<head>.*?</head>.*<body>.*</body>.*</html>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(compile);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(html);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Valid html");
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid html");
}
```

But if html has 2 of <head> element, it also checks valid html.
How to check valid html structure efficiently?

Comment: Tried pushing it through an XML parser and making sure a html, head and body element are present?

Comment: Naturally; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454. If all you're looking for is a `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` inside an `<html></html>`, then just search for the `indexOf` each, starting from the end of the last thing found, and make sure they're all there in order.

Comment: Steven// Can you recommend some XML parser?

Comment: Yet another "How can I do X using Y?"  Where Y is an entirely inappropriate tool to achieve X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about parsing HTML using Regex and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394457/question-about-parsing-html-using-regex-and-java)

Comment: Standard Java (not ancient versions) have it's own XML parses if you want to use them. See http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using some library to do it? I recommend JSoup.