# Java Splitting string including patterns into an Array

Tags: java, html, arrays, regex

I'm trying to pseudo translate the text embedded within HTML in a string. I don't want to touch the actual html tags or its attributed, just the content.

So for example, if I have something like:

```
<td colspan='2'><a>This is a Text in <b>Bold</b></a></td>
```

I want this to be eventually modified into

```
<td colspan='2'><a>Thìs ís à Tèxt îñ <b>Bòlð</b></a></td>
```

1) I can't use any third party libraries, so I'm using standard regex to parse html
2) I tried both pattern.match() and pattern.split() but both seem to have a few limitations. pattern.split() helps with splitting the string based on a regex pattern, but I lose the actual pattern in that process. Pattern.match helps with retaining the pattern, but I can't guarentee the markup.

So ideally I would want something to take the string with HTML and break it into an array like

```
array[0]: HTML Tag
array[1]: Plain Text
array[2]: HTML Tag
array[3]: Plain Text
array[4]: HTML Tag
array[5]: Plain Text
array[6]: HTML Tag
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'd look into an HTML parsing lib like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to do what you want

Comment: @RyanJ in his question he states: `1) I can't use any third party libraries, so I'm using standard regex to parse html`

Comment: Show us the code that you are using at the moment.

Comment: Forcing you to use regex for parsing any html/xml style language is lunacy.  The first rule of regex re:html is `don't parse html with regex`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question about parsing HTML using Regex and Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394457/question-about-parsing-html-using-regex-and-java)

Answer (score 0):

As regex, you could use [this one](https://regex101.com/r/jG0bZ7/1):

```
(?<=>)[^>]+(?=<)
```

I'm assuming here that you have a replace function that can take a captured group and mingle its text:

```
String str = "<td colspan='2'><a>This is a Text in <b>Bold</b></a></td>";
str.replaceAll("(?<=>)[^>]+(?=<)","");
```

However, without knowing how you intend to "pseudotranslate" a string, we can't really help you further. For custom replacement methods, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20999446/1150683) may be useful.