# Getting java variable's value from URL contents

Tags: java

For learning purpose i am trying to write a simple currency converter. I want to get the updated rate from Google.

```
public void Google() throws IOException {
    String url="https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=BDT";
    URL theUrl=new URL(url);
    URLConnection openUrl=theUrl.openConnection();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openUrl.getInputStream()));
    String result=null;
    while ((result=input.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(result);

    }
    input.close();

}
```

It gets me the html source:

```
<div id=currency_converter_result>1 USD = <span class=bld>77.9284 BDT</span>
```

**So i only need the rate 77.9284 BDT and store it in a variable.**

I am not getting any idea how to do it! Do i need somekind of regex?

Any help will be appreciated  !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To extract the DOM elements effectively, you can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library to parse the html content.

Please use the below code snippet (`import org.jsoup package` at class level) for your requirement:

```
    public void google() throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=BDT").get();
        Element element = doc.getElementById("currency_converter_result");
        String text = element.text();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

Comment: This solutions very close to my needs. Is it possible to get only the BDT result which is in <span class="bld>?

Comment: Elements r = element.getElementsByClass("bld"); worked

Comment: You can use substring: String dollarValue = text.substring(text.indexOf("=")+2);

Answer (score 0):

You can use jSoup library it parses html data in java And from there you can get the value of the span with class bdt.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library, you can use the `Pattern` class but is not a good idea to parse HTML/XML with regex. See this post:  [Question about parsing HTML using Regex and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394457/question-about-parsing-html-using-regex-and-java)

```
public void Google() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=BDT");
    URLConnection openUrl = url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openUrl.getInputStream()));

    String result = null;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*.?[0-9]* BDT)");

    while ((result = input.readLine()) != null) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            break;
        }
    }
    input.close();
}
```